# Duplicate Entries added in store while downloadind data issue in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am having problem in downloading data into store. Problem is When I download data first time then some stores contains duplicate Entries.But if I close the app without clearing data and again login then store contains valid data.
This issue I face on device only not on Browser.
Please provide some solution or some idea.
Thanks.